# Scroll View has ambiguous content size

Tags: ios, swift

I'm following the Developing iOS 11 Apps with Swift on youtube. Professor Hegarty solves the "Ambiguous content size" warning when creating a Scroll View by setting the Scroll View's intrinsic size to "Placeholder" rather than "Default (System Defined)" It worked for him, but not for me. How do I get rid of this warning?

For reference, here is where he does it: https://youtu.be/B281mrPUGjg?t=3868

Answer (score 0):

you need to disable "Contents Layout Guides" Button and your error will be gone.
all you need to do just go to your storyboard and click to scroll view and then go to show the size inspector and disable the button. i'm also attaching a image so you can understand [image]